# Jenkins No such file or directory error. But the file exists

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a problem with running bash script as a job in Jenkins (Execute shell step). Basically I narrowed my script to be one line now to test why Jenkins fails to run it. Here it is:

```
waxsim
```

So it is just one line. That should give me this output when ran without parameters:

```
No app-path was specified!
usage: waxsim [options] app-path
example: waxsim -s 2.2 /path/to/app.app
Available options are:
    -s sdk  Version number of sdk to use (-s 3.1)
    -f family   Device to use (-f ipad)
    -e VAR=value    Environment variable to set (-e CFFIXED_HOME=/tmp/iphonehome)
    -a  Available SDKs
    -v path Output video recording at path
    -h  Prints out this wonderful documentation!
```

Jenkins runs as a jenkins user. When the job is ran it fails with:

```
+ waxsim
/var/folders/gx/t63prwt53w7gr2jjt9k66q9800009c/T/hudson4478539334800834890.sh: 
line 3: waxsim: No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

When I execute `waxsim` manually, logged in as a jenkins user, everything works fine. It works for every user on the machine. It does not work only when executed in Jenkins job. Anyone knows what may be the issue?

I tried specifying the full path to `waxsim`, which is: `/usr/bin/waxsim` but it makes no difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why it works when ran in the Terminal and it doesn't when ran by Jenkins turned out to be trivial.

In the Terminal I run bash, and Jenkins is using shell. Thus, adding exporting the PATH to the Jenkins' execute shell script solved the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by **adding exporting the PATH to the Jenkins'**?

Comment: Can you, please, clarify it somehow more to the deep?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by adding exporting the PATH to the Jenkins?

Comment: I don't understand the answer either, but adding [ sh "echo This is a Workarround to avoid java.io.FileNotFoundException > workarround.txt" ]  as first step, solved execution in my case. For some reason workspace/ directory is not created without it.

Comment: `export PATH= "path/path/"`

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding `#!/bin/bash` to the top of your shell execution should give you the desired results.